# Start change detection for child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a requirement to switch-off 'changeDetection' for parent component and switch-on 'changeDetection' for the child component. Can you give me an example of this functionality?

In the parent component, I have static data - so there's no need of change detection here. But it gives performance issues in IE 11, so we decided to remove change detection in the parent component. But in the child component, we are having forms - so we need change detection here. How can I add change detection for the child component only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `changeDetector.markForCheck()` or `changeDetector.detectChanges();` in child component when you think you need to run or prepare your component to detect changes.

Don`t forget to inject ChangeDetectorRef in component contstructor():

```
constructor(private changeDetecor: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```